# Tracking template lpurl takes you back to the specified final url? How does it work technically?

Tags: google-ads-api

According to this article, https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6076199

When you define a final URL as your landing page, you can use URL options to manage your tracking and redirect information.

So, my website is example.com and the 3rd party service I use is called 3rdpartytracker.com
Let's say that I own the 3rdpartytracker website too.

http://www.3rdpartytracker.com/rd?keyword={_mykwid}&ad={creative}&url={lpurl}

Do I have to set a redirection script into 3rdpartytracker.com to send me back to the example.com ?

Or it will take me automatically back ?
I mean how does this work in a more technical approach ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you own the both 3rdpartytracker.com and example.com then, yes, you will have to set a redirection script on 3rdpartytracker.com to extract the `url` parameter from the request to 3rdpartytracker.com and redirect to the `url` parameter value (in this case example.com).

I actually think that [this blogpost](http://adwords.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/get-faster-and-easier-url-tracking-with.html) provides a clearer explanation of Upgraded URLs in AdWords.

And if you can explain this to somebody else without mistakenly saying [Final Destination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Destination) then you're a better person than me!